# jdbc error creating table

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, derby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create autoincrement key in Java DB using NetBeans IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308329/create-autoincrement-key-in-java-db-using-netbeans-ide)

I am trying to create a table in netbeans, using -

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    P_Id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (P_Id)
)
```

but am getting the following error -

> Syntax error: Encountered "AUTO_INCREMENT" at line 3, column 19.
>   Line 1, column 1

Comment: Using Netbeans 7.2 and Mysql database I have no problem running your query. What database are you connected to?

Comment: I am using Netbeans 7.2 adn mysql database too. But. i get an error when i execute the sql command

Comment: I am using derby, and not mysql.. Sorry, for the mistake

Comment: @ user997478 : Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308329/create-autoincrement-key-in-java-db-using-netbeans-ide

Comment: If you get a syntax error, why not just look up the right syntax in the [reference manual](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/ref/)?

Comment: Please read the Derby manual for the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the underscore. I think you can also combine the primary key declaration with the column like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    P_Id integer primary key autoincrement,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255)
)
```