# BEFORE INSERT in Derby DB

Tags: database, derby

At the moment my application uses an Oracle db and I am really happy about it.
My intention is to implement the same app with Derby (just to make it more portable).
With Oracle I use a trigger with 'BEFORE INSERT' and a sequence and it works ok.
I would like to implement the same with Derby, but it seams impossible.
I also found this article: [Sequences and Triggers in Derby DB](https://github.com/nielskrijger/blog/blob/master/posts/2014-01-29-sequences-and-triggers-in-derby-db.md)
Is the content of the article correct ? Why Derby does not have such a common feature implemented ?

Thanks Alb

This is what I used in oracle:

```
CREATE TABLE  "SITES" 
("SITE_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"SITE_NAME" VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"SITE_LINK" VARCHAR2(500) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"SITE_DESC" VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"SITE_DATA_IN" DATE, 
 CONSTRAINT "SITE_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("SITE_ID") ENABLE
)

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "SITES_TRIGGER" 
before insert on SITES
for each row
begin
select SITES_SEQ.nextval into :new.SITE_ID from dual;
end;
/
ALTER TRIGGER  "SITES_TRIGGER" ENABLE
/

CREATE SEQUENCE   "SITES_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 301 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE
```

Comment: use h2 then. Does it have to be derby?

Comment: What's the sequence for? What's the information used for? Do you use JDBC, JPA oder something else to deal with your data?

Comment: Also if you are calling derby from java code this is not a question related to java, but only to derby. Remove the tag java please.

Comment: @Constantin, no does not have to be derby, but because I am developing on Netbeans, it seamed to me the easier.

Comment: @Brian I edited the question, with what I used

Comment: Ok, using a sequence for a primary key. So, how do you persist data? Via JDBC or JPA or something?!

Comment: I use hibernate to populate the table, apart for the primary key (incremented by the sql code above)

Comment: http://database-management.softwareinsider.com/compare/6-16/Apache-Derby-vs-H2

Comment: @gocan76 You should use Hibernate for the primary key column too. This way you would not need triggers at all - or at least not for the primary key. This would make your application more portable, just as you desire it to be.

Comment: I think I will opt for the hibernate solution, Constantin pointed out an interesting option also

Comment: In the end, after some testing, to make things simple, I followed this solution, and it works (in my app) perfectly, thanks to all Alb http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308329/create-autoincrement-key-in-java-db-using-netbeans-ide

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation of v10.11](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/ref/index.html), Derby does support before-insert-triggers.

Comment: ok Brian, I tried myself, but with no luck, then when I came across that article I decided to ask here, just not to waste other time.

Comment: @gocan76: what happened when you tried. Did you get an error message? What line of code returned the error?

Comment: @BryanPendleton, ...... CREATE TRIGGER COUNTER_TRG
AFTER INSERT ON SITES
REFERENCING NEW AS NEWROW 
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
UPDATE SITES O
SET O.SITE_ID = NEXT VALUE FOR COUNTER_SEQ; .......This is the error: Error code 30000, SQL state 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "SET" at line 7, column 1.