# I get this error "Error code 30000, SQL state 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "AUTO_INCREMENT" at line 3, column 22." when I create a sql table

Tags: java, sql, derby

```
CREATE TABLE Products
(
Item_ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
item_make varchar(255) NOT NULL,
item_model varchar(255),
brought_in_date varchar(255),
collected_date varchar(255),
whats_wrong varchar(255),
what_was_done varchar(255),
Price varchar(255),
CID varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (Item_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (CID) REFERENCES Customers(CID)
)
```

When I execute this I get this error

```
  Error code 30000, SQL state 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "AUTO_INCREMENT" at line 3, column 22.
```

I am using sql on the java database, derby

Does anyone know what I did wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308329/create-autoincrement-key-in-java-db-using-netbeans-ide
Refer to post made by Sam

Comment: From the code it seems to be mysql

Comment: @Naranca I'm not sure which parts of the code suggests this is MySQL, and given the edit it seems to be Derby

Comment: I might be wrong but the error part is what I consider mysql

Comment: @Naranca For MySQL I would expect an error message _"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AUTO_INCREMENT' at line 3"_ (if use of `AUTO_INCREMENT` would have been a syntax error in MySQL).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `AUTO_INCREMENT` (which is MySQL dialect), you should use the SQL standard [`GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY`](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/ref/rrefsqlj37836.html) as supported by Derby:

```
CREATE TABLE Products
(
Item_ID int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY not null primary key,
item_make varchar(255) NOT NULL,
item_model varchar(255),
brought_in_date varchar(255),
collected_date varchar(255),
whats_wrong varchar(255),
what_was_done varchar(255),
Price varchar(255),
CID varchar(255),
FOREIGN KEY (CID) REFERENCES Customers(CID)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Accordign to the Derby definition table page the syntax would be something like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS
 (
 ITEM_ID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1,  INCREMENT BY 1)
 ...
 UNIQUE (MAP_ID)
 )
```

Link here [derby docs](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.0/manuals/develop/develop132.html)

Comment: Note that specifying `(start with 1, increment by 1)` is not required, as that is the default.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel right, that case would be to start a new DB with a new empty table.