# Adding data to MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql

For a testing purposes i created a form with 2 jTextFields, button and a table. I'm trying to add data to database. But i seem to run into a problem. When i press the button, it returns fail message because the data haven't been added to database. I'd appreciate any help. So here's what i'm doing. I created ConnectionConfiguration class to simplify code:

```
public class ConnectionConfiguration {
    public static Connection getConnection() {
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("Connection Success");
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Connection Failed");
    }
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/systemnew?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "root","123456");
        System.out.println("Database Connected");
    } catch (SQLException se){
        System.out.println("No Database" + se);
    }
    return connection;
    }   
}
```

Connection is always success and database always connects. The error message states that my mistake is here (at systemnew.UpdateDatabase.add).Here's add method from UpdateDatabase class:

```
public boolean add(String field1, String field2) {
    try {
        Connection conn = ConnectionConfiguration.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO newtable(field1,field2) VALUES('"+field1+"','"+field2+"')");
        ps.executeUpdate();
        return true;
    } catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

and here's the code for button that should potentially add data to database:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    if(new UpdateDatabase().add(jTextField1.getText(),jTextField2.getText())){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Added successfully!");
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record has not been added!");
    }
}
```

Error

```
Connection Success
Database Connected
java.sql.SQLException: Field 'tblid' doesn't have a default value
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:963)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3966)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3902)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2673)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2549)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2009)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5098)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1994)
    at systemnew.UpdateDatabase.add(UpdateDatabase.java:38)
```

Comment: post the complete error message

Comment: @sidgate http://pastebin.com/raw/WZwdh5xz Line "at systemnew.UpdateDatabase.add(UpdateDatabase.java:38)" is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells the specific issue

```
java.sql.SQLException: Field 'tblid' doesn't have a default value
```

Your table `newtable` seems to have non-null `tblid` column for which you are not specifying any value during insert. You may want to mark it as `auto increment`

Comment: I seem to be having the biggest tunnel vision. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In you table `newtable` there is a field called `tblid` which you are not assigning a value to so you get the following error

> Field 'tblid' doesn't have a default value

BTW it would be safer to use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) in order to avoid possible Sql Injection

Also consider this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3334983/2310289) to find out about auto incrementing id fields

Comment: Thanks to you too. If i may ask, where am i not using PreparedStatement?

Comment: Sorry you are - my bad.  Try using replaceable parameters `?` and then `setString` etc.

Comment: you mean something like this? PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO newtable(field1,field2) VALUES(?,?)"); ps.setString(1,textField.getText()); etc.

Comment: Yep, looks good.  Maybe want to trim your getText value though